# Autofill fields in Access Form

Tags: ms-access

**The Scenario** 
I am designing a database to digitize many carbon records of different fish, the prices, quantity sold, and the selling firm.

I have one table called `MainFishNames` with a field called `CommonNames` (the names that will be entered in the form) and a field called `CategoryID`, and another table called `Category`, with 2 fields: `Category`, and `CategoryID`.

**The Goal** 
For ease of data entry, I am trying to program a field in the form to autofill to the fish category i.e. Pelagic, Bottom, etc... based on the fish name they enter in another field.

**The Issue** 
I've already successfully programmed another field to autofill the firm name based on the firm ID using `DLookup` in the control source, but I haven't figured out how to do the same for when I am not looking up a value based on an ID.

Every time I try this using `DLookup` I receive an Error in the field.  Is this possible using `DLookup`, or should I go about this another way?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide your SQL, any pertinent code, and the error you are receiving.

Comment: Newd, I am using this expression in the control source under the data tab for the field I am trying to work with: =DLookUp(" [Category]![Category]","[Category]"," [MainFishNames]![CommonName]   = " & [Combo43]).  Combo 43 refers to the combo box of "CommonName" for the different fish names to choose from.  Category is the name of the table, and the variable (I am going to change that to make it less confusing).

Comment: @Newd, the error I'm receiving is #Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correct that MainFishNames contains a field called CategoryID that is the FK for the Category table, then you will need a nested DLookup to first find the CategoryID, then use that as the criteria for the Category Name:

```
=DLookup("[Category]", "Category", "[CategoryID] = " & DLookup("[CategoryID]", "MainFishNames", "[CommonNames] = '" & Forms!Prices!Combo43 & "'"))
```

That being said, using DLookups can impact performance, and might not be advisable for every control. If your form is bound to the MainFishNames table, using a subform bound to the Category table should be a simpler and faster solution.

Comment: Thank you @Christopher, I used a nested DLookup and got error #Name?, so I decided to try with a subform. My form isn't bound to the MainFishNames table, I created a new table called "Prices" to fill. I linked the "CommonName" field from the MainFishNames table in the Price table before making the form, so there is a dropdown list of the available fish to choose from when entering the price data. I created a subform with the "Category" field, but I seem to have the same problem where I can't figure out how to make the subform autofill based on the contents of the CommonName field.

Comment: Are you referencing your controls properly? What did you type in place of `Forms!MyFormName!MyFishNameEntryControl`?

Comment: I believe so, I used Forms!Prices!ItemDescription in place of that (the name of the field I'm referencing to autofill the field I'm working on). I've noticed another problem though, when I fill in the form fields that reference other tables, that new data ends up on the referenced tables, and not on the form based on the "Prices" table. Is what I'm trying to do possible in Access?  I'm a bit new with it, but I'm trying to create a layout for data entry of fish prices, fish and the selling firm, and use the tables I've already included to help in the process by acting as a constant reference.

Comment: What is the name of your form? `Forms!Prices!ItemDescription` does not seem to relate to anything we have talked about so far. Based on your comment to Newd, the combobox the user is selecting the common name from is called `Combo43`. So we now have, `Forms!MyFormName!Combo43` so far. Your form name is the value displayed in the title bar of the form window, or tab if you have your system set that way. It's also the name shown in the navigation pane when you are opening the form for the first time. What is that name?

Comment: Based on your difficulties of overwriting table values, you are likely using a bound form. That might be the correct thing to do, but I would urge you to research the difference between bound vs. unbound forms and analyze your table structure and control properties. If you still have an issue with that I would suggest creating a new question focused on your form design issue. As I understand it, there shouldn't be any problem getting Access to achieve your goals, but you will certainly need to some research or power through a handful of tutorials.

Comment: The name of my form is Prices.  Sorry for the confusion: I labeled Combo43 as ItemDescription, I've tried using both Combo43 and Item Description and access seems to recognize them both when I begin typing them into the expression box.  Thank you for you advice on bound vs. unbound forms.  It looks like more research may still be needed... I am quite new at access.

Comment: Using the label name will not give an error, but it will not work correctly. You must use the object name: `Combo43`. You may also need to have this expression recalculate `AfterUpdate` of `Combo43` so it looks for the new selection. The code to enter in the code builder would be, simply: `Me!MyExpressionFieldsObjectName.Requery` where MyExpressionFieldsObjectName = the actual object name, like Combo43, but for the control holding the nested DLookup. That way, each new selection will reevaluate the nested Dlookups and give you the correct category. Welcome to Stack Overflow btw!